# Changing the Default Editor on Octave comes with an Error Message

Tags: octave

I changed my default Octave editor to Notepad++ with the following lines:

```
EDITOR('C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\notepad++\notepad++.exe');
edit ("editor", sprintf ("%s %%S", EDITOR()))
edit mode async
```

Notepad pops up when I write edit and it works fine. But every time I open Octave CLI, following errors come up:

```
error: The EDITOR option of edit has been removed.  Use EDITOR() directly.
error: called from
    edit at line 165 column 9
    C:\Users\emiry\.octaverc at line 8 column 1
```

How can I change the editor without triggering an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the warning is coming from the second line

```
edit ("editor", sprintf ("%s %%S", EDITOR()))
```

if you look at `help edit`
you will notice that `editor` is not used anymore.
The setting is your first line

```
EDITOR('C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\notepad++\notepad++.exe');
```