# Open specific .m file with Notepad++ custom file editor in Octave 6.2.0 (GUI)

Tags: notepad++, octave, octave-gui

I'm using Octave 6.2.0 with Notepad++ as the custom file editor. When I type `edit myfunction` from the CLI, the file opens normally, but when I type the same thing from the GUI, the last file that I had open in Notepad++ displays, as if I had opened Notepad++ by itself from Windows Explorer (I'm using Windows 10). In the GUI, it's the same behavior as typing `edit` without an argument, whereas it works as expected in the CLI. It seems that my GUI is ignoring the `edit` function input argument, and passing the argument as a string in parentheses, i.e. `edit('myfunction')` or `edit('myfunction.m')` didn't help. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: See this similar question:
[Changing the Default Editor on Octave comes with an Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361356/changing-the-default-editor-on-octave-comes-with-an-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the GUI octave ignores the EDITOR env variable, and uses the built-in editor.

However, in the preferences / editor dialogue of the octave gui, there is an option to specify a custom editor. This will probably do what you want.

Comment: I have the custom editor set to Notepad++, which indeed does switch to using that program over the native Octave editor, but still only the CLI version will open a specific .m file with the `edit` function, whereas the GUI opens it like Windows Explorer does, bringing up the most recently viewed file.

Comment: If you read that section properly, it mentions that `%f` will be substituted with the filename, and `%l` will be substituted with the line number. This means you need to use these to tell notepad++ which file to open (and at which line, if necessary), in the same way you would do this if you were invoking notepad++ from the commandline. If the only thing you have in that box is `notepad++`, then basically whenever you invoke the edit command, octave runs the `notepad++` command, without arguments, which simply opens notepad++ (and it so happens that notepad++ opens in 'most recent file' mode).

Comment: tl;dr: replace `notepad++` with `notepad++ %f`

Comment: I have the full path and .exe filename, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` in the custom file editor line, as well as `EDITOR` set to that same path/file. Using `EDITOR()` in that line causes an error window to say that Octave cannot start that custom file editor, and adding `%f` to either the full path/file or to `EDITOR()` causes a similar error message box.

Comment: EDITOR is not relevant here. This is a GUI preference. All the above is for the relevant edit field in the GUI preferences. Try using double quotes around the whole thing or just "%f" (or on both the notepad++ and the %f bits separately).

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to Notepad++ and `%f` in double quotes in the custom file editor specification in the preferences menu, i.e.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%f"`

Comment: why not the whole thing in double quotes?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, that didn't work for me, but double quotes around the `%f` does. Thanks for your help with this.